# decompressing files in c# when they have been compressed using zlib

Tags: c#, zlib, compression

zlib is an appllication written in visual c++ and available online.

I have a file which was compressed using zlib in visual studio c++ application. Now I am trying to write a completely different c# program to decompress it in visual c# application. What I have done is:

1. I have a large file with .fdd extension which contains 3 compressed (using zlib) files ( ffo, sym and cff) .
2. At first, I converted the whole .fdd file into an array of bytes.
3. I located the exact location of the three files.
4. Used the loop, to copy the respective bytes of the files into another array. So that in the first iteration the array stores ffo bytes, in the second iteration it stores the sym bytes and so on.
5. Converted the copied array of bytes into a file with .zip extension so that I separate out the 3 compressed files.
6. So I named the files as Fileffo.zip, Filesym.zip and Filecff.zip.
7. Now I need to decompress the files and name the decompressed file as P.ffo, Q.sym and R.cff.
8. I just know that the .fdd file has been compressed using gzip utility. The first four bytes contain the size of the ffo file, and from the fifth byte till the size(from the first four bytes) the ffo exists, after the ffo, next four bytes contain the size of sym file and then the sym file, next four bytes contain the size of the cff file and then the cff file itself. That is why I am trying to extract the size of the respective files from the respective four bytes before them. and then trying to save the byte information from the three files separately in the array through the loop.

How can I decompress them using c#? I don't know the exact extension to use when the files have been compressed using "zlib", so I put in .zip extension.

```
public static void ExtractFile()
{

    int i = 0;
    const string zipPath = @"C:\Product Development\Development\FFPCAppTool\PCToolForFF\PCToolForFF\bin\x86\Debug\000A1C10000101.fdd";

    if (zipPath.Contains("000A1C10000101.fdd"))
    {
        byte[] arrayWholeFileInBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(zipPath);

        long fileLength = new FileInfo(zipPath).Length;

        //string testpath = @"C:\Product Development\Development\ExtractedFdd\" + ManuId + "\\" + DeviceIdentifier + "\\" + Revision + ".zip";

        const string testzippath = @"C:\Users\Himagau\Desktop\testExtract\Fileffo.zip";
        const string extractPath = @"C:\Users\Himagau\Desktop\testExtract\ ";


        while (i < fileLength)
        {
            using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(new FileStream(zipPath, FileMode.Open)))
            {
                reader.BaseStream.Seek(i, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                reader.Read(arrayWholeFileInBytes, i, 4); //reading value in bytes 

                n = BitConverter.ToInt32(arrayWholeFileInBytes, i);
                //converting first four bytes into a single integer value i.e. size of zip
                reader.Read(arrayWholeFileInBytes, i + 4, n);
                byte[] array1 = new byte[n]; //passing the size of zip into array size
                Array.Copy(arrayWholeFileInBytes, i + 4, array1, 0, n);
                File.WriteAllBytes(testzippath, array1);

                ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(testzippath, extractPath);

                i = i + n + 4;

            }
        }

    }
}
```

zipfile & zip archive are giving the errors like `central directory not found` and when the change the extension of file to .gz from .zip then gzipstream is giving the error as "not a valid gzip file."

Comment: I added a space in the value of `extractPath` so that the coloring on this site won't freak out. Just to be aware.

Comment: Have you looked at [GZipStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.gzipstream(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Given the example of the first several bytes provided in the comments below, `E7 6B 00 00 78 9C EC BD 07 7C 1C C9 75 26 DE 35 33 C0 00 20 72 06 08 22 31 81 39 67 2E D3`, the bytes starting with `78 9C` is a [*zlib*](http://zlib.net/) stream.  Not zip.  Not gzip.  zlib.  Those are three different formats.

You can use [DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/)'s ZlibCodec methods to decompress that.

Comment: 1. the first 30 hex bytes of .fdd file are: F2 BD 57 73 3F 54 D0 DB B3 7B 14 E0 C8 AA 3D 7A E9 DE 84 ED 56 D0 9B B0 AB 14 EC FA FD 84

Comment: yes, I have a document which states: zipped file(*fdd) containing FFO(*ffo), SYM(*sym), CFF(*cff),CIF(*cif, if present), DD Stack Info File (*tsk). Zipped definition is give as: A file has been compressed using gzip utility, will be said to have been "zipped".

Comment: 2. I am reading the whole .fdd file as an array of bytes using---

Comment: byte[] arrayWholeFileInBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(zipPath);

Comment: I see nothing recognizable in those bytes.  That is not the start of a zip file or a gzip file.  Can you provide a link to the document?  By the way, gzip is not zipped.  Those are two different formats.  The author of the document may be confused.

Comment: 3. According to the document, the first 4 bytes contain the size of the .ffo file. So inside the while loop, I am first reading the first 4 bytes, converting the 4 bytes into an integer value to get the size of the ffo and then reading the arraywholefileinbytes from 5th byte to the size obtained(27623) from first four bytes, then I read from byte[27627] to byte[27631] which gives me the size(2216) of sym file(after converting 4 bytes into integer value) and so on.....

Comment: How do you get 27623 from `F2 BD 57 73`?  Those four bytes are 1935130098 or 4072494963 depending on whether the integer is stored little endian or big endian.

Comment: the first four bytes are 231, 107, 0, 0 which after being converted together(four bytes at once) to decimal gives 27623. according to my code.

Comment: Then you did not provide the first 30 bytes of the file.  What are the bytes you provided?

Comment: 231 107 0 0 120 156 236 189 7 124 28 201 117 38 222 53 51 192 0 32 114 6 8 34 49 129 57 103 46 211......these are the values that I can see when I debug the code, from arraywholefilebytes[0] to arraywholefilebytes[29]. These are not in hex format I guess. I can see these simple decimal values in byte array.

Comment: "E7-6B-00-00-78-9C-EC-BD-07-7C-1C-C9-75-26-DE-35-33-C0-00-20-72-06-08-22-31-81-39-67-2E-D3-this what I get if I convert the first 30 bytes to hex using bitconverter

Comment: Ok, _now_ we're talking.  This is what I asked for in the first place.

Comment: If I use : byte[] newarray1 = Ionic.Zlib.ZlibStream.UncompressBuffer(array1);

Comment: after the "Array.Copy(arrayWholeFileInBytes, i + 4, array1, 0, n);" I am getting an error "Bad state (incorrect data check)"

Comment: I can't help you further.  Good luck.  What you posted is a valid zlib stream, so if fed properly to that method, it will decompress.